# Read a struct sent by a c++ program to a struct python

Tags: python, c++, struct, udp, udpclient

So my question is quite unique and I couldn't find any easy solution for it online.

I got a C++ program which sends UDP packets that are basically array of structs

```
struct Player {
    std::string name;
    int team_number;
}
```

Now I got another Python script which receives those packets.

My goal here is to read the packets directly to a `Player` struct in my Python script.

Can that be done?

Comment: Of course it can be done, what is the problem?

Comment: You can't send a `std::string` through a network packet like that. You're going to have to serialize it or use a POD struct.

Comment: I will make it `char[32]`

Comment: Since the question relates to a Python script receiving UDP packets, I don't see how it relates to c++. I recommend removing that tag.

Comment: That'll help. Then look at the [Python struct module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

Comment: Have you considered serialising it as a JSON object which Python could parse pretty easily?

Comment: The struct module seems helpful, but I cant seem to find the correct parsing for `char[32]; int; float; float; float; float` for example

Comment: nvm got it `struct.unpack("32sifff", data)`

Comment: Just beware of byte order and padding issues.